# React-native create a performant grid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, grid

In my app i need to create a grid like on screenshot:

[Grid that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V06eo.jpg)

Cells width and count depends on selected date on top.
Every cell should handle touches (passing timestamp and numbers on the left).

Currently i use the simple "View" component from react-native with borders on left and top. 
When i tap on date on top it takes about 0.5 - 1 seconds (depends on cells count) to rerender. 
Is there a more performant way to make a grid like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of creating performant grids and repeating blocks of data are the ListView or FlatList components.  I don't have any experience with the FlatList as it's pretty new but ListView has optimizations that help it with rendering by only rendering the elements that are currently on the screen.

I believe both of those elements can do vertical or horizontal scrolling but I don't think they can do both.  Not positive about that.

If you need both horizontal and vertical scrolling, you may need to wrap the list component in a scroll view.  Basically, you'd make the list as wide as necessary, even if it's bigger than the screen.  The list itself handles the vertical scrolling and the scroll view handles the horizontal scrolling (or vice versa if it's wider than it is tall).

Additionally, there are a lot of performance enhancements that you can look into for React:

- React 16 may be faster for you as it has a new diffing engine and allows for prioritization in the rendering engine.
- You can try creating a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` function.
- I've also seen people claim performance enhancements by not putting their repeating components (the cells in the grid) in classes but using pure functions instead. Unfortunately, I can't turn up the blog post right now
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement grid is using `FlatList` component and it is recommended for this (see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)). You can use the `numColumns` and `columnWrapperStyle` properties and apply them a variable to style your grid dynamically. `FlatList` is easy to use and you can see a great document and useful examples [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/flatlist.html#flatlist).